# How to change action layout of menu item in bottom navigation?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Action Layout is not working in Bottom Navigation.
My item:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_in_progress"
 android:enabled="true" 
android:actionLayout="@layout/in_progress_layout"
 android:title="@string/in_progress_screen_title"
 app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

But it only show toolbar but not in my navigation.So,Can anyone help me please